# Prolog Analogy IQ Test Unexpected token exception

Tags: prolog

I am trying to develop a program that will be able to solve an analogy IQ test. As you can see below I've written the figures and relations as facts and I've also made an analogy Predicate that should return one figure number when given three other figure numbers. The first two figures are connected through a relation and the 3rd and 4th are also connected through the same relation.

For example, analogy should work like this: analogy(1,5,3,X). X=7.

```
figure 1 -> middle(triangle, square)
figure 5 -> middle(square, triangle)
relation between 1 & 5 -> inverse
figure 3 -> middle(square, circle)
figure 7 -> middle(circle, square)
relation between 3 & 7 -> inverse
```

when I compile the code I get the following exception: file test lab 1.ecl, line 105: syntax error: unexpected token
|   figure(S1, _(Sh1,Sh2)),
|                   ^ here

What do I do wrong?

```
figure(1, middle(triangle, square)).
figure(2, middle(circle, triangle)).
figure(3, middle(square, circle)).
figure(4, middle(square, square)).
figure(5, middle(square, triangle)).
figure(6, middle(triangle, circle)).
figure(7, middle(circle, square)).
figure(8, middle(triangle, triangle)).
figure(9, samepattern(lowerleft, circle)).
figure(10, samepattern(upperleft, circle)).
figure(11, samepattern(lowerright, circle)).
figure(12, samepattern(upperright, circle)).
figure(13, samepattern(upperleft, square)).
figure(14, samepattern(lowerleft, square)).
figure(15, samepattern(upperright, square)).
figure(16, samepattern(lowerright, square)).

relation(middle(S1,S2), middle(S2,S1), inverse).
relation(samepattern(S1,S2), samepattern(S1,S3), spinverse).


analogy(S1,S2,S3,S4):-
    figure(S1, _(Sh1,Sh2)),
    figure(S2, _(Sh3,Sh4)),
    relation(_(Sh1,Sh2),_(Sh3,Sh4),R),
    figure(S3, _(Sh5,Sh6)),
    figure(S4, _(Sh7,Sh8)),
    relation(_(Sh5,Sh6),_(Sh7,Sh8),R).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **name** of a term must be an **atom**. Thus, a term such as `_(X,Y)` is not accepted (because `_` is a variable) and causes a syntax error. Thus, you need to modify the definition of predicate `analogy/4`as following:

```
analogy(S1,S2,S3,S4):-
    figure(S1, F1),
    figure(S2, F2),
    relation(F1, F2, R),
    figure(S3, F3),
    figure(S4, F4),
    relation(F3, F4, R).
```

Observe that, in the predicate `analogy/4`, the specific arguments in figures denoted by terms `F1`, `F2`, `F3` and `F4` are not accessed individually and, consequently, it is not necessary to name each one of them explicitly.

Running example:

```
?- analogy(1,5,3,X).
X = 7 ;
false.
```

Comment: Thanks so much mate. Sorry I am a noob.